# Load balancing PostgreSQL with Windows Servers

Tags: windows, postgresql, replication, load-balancing, pgpool

I have a question concerning the possibilities of load balancing when using PostgreSQL with Windows Servers. On Unix systems this is made possible by using pgpool-II. How can I achieve the same with Windows?

I know that you cannot mix systems when it comes to replication. Pgpool documentation states:

> **Can I mix different platforms of PostgreSQL as pgpool-II backends, for example Linux and Windows?**
>
> In streaming replication mode, no

What about a different scenario? Can I run pgpool on a Unix machine, and configure replication & load balancing on a pool of Windows Servers?

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 in case it matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I run pgpool on a Unix machine, and configure replication & load balancing on a pool of Windows Servers?

Yes, you can. That's probably the best option in your situation, barring porting PgPool-II to Windows.

However, I suspect that load balancing across read replicas isn't necessary most of the time people do it, and that appropriate database tuning, indexing and configuration is often sufficient.